# what is range of attime in OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl, der

I need to check the validity of few certificates and am using `-attime` flag with my OpenSSL command

`openssl cms -verify -inform DER *** -attime epochvalue`.

I got a doubt here, about the data type of ***epochvalue***, then had a look at the link

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-s_server.html

in which it is mentioned as ***[-attime intmax]***. I believe ***intmax*** mentioned here same as `INT_MAX` of `limits.h`

If ***attime*** range is only till `INT_MAX`, which when converts to epoch will be *2147483647* and is nothing but till *Tuesday, January 19, 2038 3:14:07*, how will the certificates after this date will be validated?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: @choppe, since `int` cannot handle more than `INT_MAX` what is the way to support beyond that date?